# Agregação de dados em desenvolvimento PHP e MVC

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Bom dia!

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web e estou com dúvidas sobre a organização enquanto estrutura MVC. Existe um cadastro de empresas que já possui classe/modelo/controle etc.
Minha dúvida refere-se aos endereços de uma empresa (que é uma agregação do cadastro de empresas). Precisarei criar um modelo para ele... como melhor alocar o carregamento desse modelo (tenho um autoloading para os modelos principais, mas não para a agregação).

Comment: Sua duvida de basei apenar em melhor método de load para esta agregação ou na construção desta agregação?

Comment: Olá, Guilherme. Se baseia em melhor método de load (já que não "usa" autoloading); o relacionamento/agregação no DB já está ok. Minha dúvida está relacionada no "acoplamento": melhores práticas para incluir e acoplamento com o controller (no caso, da empresa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom como você disse é uma **Agregação** ou seja eles tem o mesmo nível hierárquico, sendo um independente do outro, mas ainda sim relacionados.
Para definir o melhor método de load você tera que verificar seus critérios de frequência de uso, creio que se você usa constantemente dados desta agregação, seja melhor manter ele iniciado já no construtor:

```
require_once CONTROLLERS.'EnderecoController.php';

class Empresa {
    function __construct(){

        $this->endereco = new EnderecoController();
    }
}
```

Aqui o controlador de `Endereco` esta sempre ativo junto com a empresa, ou seja ele vai carregar sempre os dois arquivos.

Agora se você utiliza apenas em alguns casos específicos, seja melhor
realizar um loader de chamada:

```
Class App{
    function __get($var){
        $controller = sprintf('%sController', ucword($var));
        if(!isset($this->{$var}) && file_exists(CONTROLLERS."{$controller}.php")){
            $this->{$var} = new $controller;
        }

        if(!isset($this->{$var})){
            echo "Variable {$var} not found!";
        }

        return $this->{$var};
    }
}

Class Empresa extends App{

    function AddEnderecoEmpresa(){
        $this->endereco->save($cdEmpresa);
    }

}
```

Aqui ele vai carregar `Endereco` apenas quando necessitar usar.

Comment: Opa, Guilherme! Agregação sim! E sua resposta veio de encontro com o que imaginava mesmo! E, continuando, a primeira opção será a mais adequada porque sempre haverá o vinculo! Vlw!